# Как вывести только один пункт меню?

Tags: wordpress

Есть ли возможность вывести только один пункт меню, обычно получаемого с помощью функции wp_nav_menu ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция [wp_get_nav_menu_items()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/) возвращает все пункты меню в виде массива. Выберите из результата необходимый вам элемент и выводите только его.